# Getting error when executing smartjmx through jmeter for ecommerce site

Tags: testing, jmeter, e-commerce, load-testing, blazemeter

I have recorded the smart jmx of ecommerce site with blaze meter but when i'm using the same file in jmeter getting error's. It's working fine till add to cart, when it processing the customer information throw exceptions.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfVSc.png)

Comment: did you add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan?

Comment: yes, already added cookie manager

Answer (score 1):

SmartJMX is a commercial third party tool by [Blazemeter](https://www.blazemeter.com) and its code is non public.

As such it's impossible to help you, so you should contact their support to report the issue.

Most probably your issue is due to:

- Missing correlation not detected by SmartJMX
- Wrong correlation done by some extractor added by SmartJMX

You can debug this using JMeter [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) and [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) or [Debug PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_PostProcessor) and comparing a recording with a play of your script to see what differs.